# Running interactive commands in remote machine using putty command line

Tags: ssh, putty, interactive

I am trying to connect to remote terminal using putty command line with below command:
C:\Program Files>putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m  remote.cmd -t 10.127.1.1

In remote.cmd file, I want to give sudo command which requires password. e.g.
sudo username. It prompts me for password.

I want to know how can I write command in remote.cmd file to provide password for it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to open a terminal on the remote system, and then give the command you have in mind from the windows that will open in front of you. In order to do that, you have to allow X forwarding with putty. It is very easy, and the instructions are [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html). Once you have configured putty and Xming as suggested, all you need to say is:

```
putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m gnome-terminal -t 10.127.1.1 
putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m xterm -t 10.127.1.1
putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password -m konsole -t 10.127.1.1
```

One of these commands will work, depending on the desktop the linux system is using.

Comment: note, that script files need to be on the windows side called "gnome-terminal" "xterm" and "konsole" for these to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **expect** command.
Example:

```
expect "$username@$hosts's password:"
send -- "$password\n"
```

Further info at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307067/how-to-execute-sudo-commands-with-expect-send-commands-in-bash-script